# Using the Minecraft plugin language Skript, how can I find the dimension (ex. "nether") of a player?

Tags: plugins, minecraft, dimension

I'm pretty new to coding MC plugins, and I am currently making one with Skript. I need to be able to find what dimension a player is currently in, for example the nether or overworld.

However, this kind of thing doesn't work as I would expect:

```
{dimOfPlayer} = dimension of player
send "Dim: %{dimOfPlayer}%" # I get an error: "Can't understand this condition or effect"
```

Is there any way to actually get the dimension and print it to chat, or test what it is? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by checking what WORLD the player is for example if you create a normal world there should be these 3 worlds "world", "world_nether" and "world_the_end". I think So then you can check the dimension of player like this.

```
if player is in world "World name":
    #Do stuff
```